GDAL is installed but stil getting ModuleNotFoundError: No module named '_gdal' in ubuntu
I used to work with gdal in my ubuntu but after installing geany it stoped working and when I try running my code I get the error.
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named '_gdal'
this is what the sample code says:

$ python3 -c "from osgeo import gdal; print(gdal.version)"
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/home/vahid/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/osgeo/init.py", line 29, in swig_import_helper
return importlib.import_module(mname)
File "/usr/lib/python3.10/importlib/init.py", line 126, in import_module
return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
File "", line 1050, in _gcd_import
File "", line 1027, in _find_and_load
File "", line 1006, in _find_and_load_unlocked
File "", line 674, in _load_unlocked
File "", line 571, in module_from_spec
File "", line 1176, in create_module
File "", line 241, in _call_with_frames_removed
ImportError: libgdal.so.30: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory


During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:


Traceback (most recent call last):
File "", line 1, in 
File "/home/vahid/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/osgeo/init.py", line 45, in 
_gdal = swig_import_helper()
File "/home/vahid/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/osgeo/init.py", line 42, in swig_import_helper
return importlib.import_module('_gdal')
File "/usr/lib/python3.10/importlib/init.py", line 126, in import_module
return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named '_gdal'

I also checked pip list and found that I have GDAL 3.4.1 and python3 --version shows Python 3.10.12

Thank you so much @user2856 . Your comment was really helpful and it was my answer . I think it would be helpful for others if you post it as answer to this question.

OK, answer added.

GDAL is distributed on pypi as a source only package.  Don't pip install gdal unless you know what you are doing and have installed the appropriate libgdal and development tool chain including the gdal (and optional numpy) headers package.
Instead, clean up the broken pip install
pip uninstall gdal
## OR
rm -rf /home/vahid/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/osgeo 

and then install from your package manager
sudo apt install gdal-bin python3-gdal

